# Trying to replace special character in dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe column that looks like this:
    [image]

and i'm trying to replace the '-' sign with ''. However if I try:

```
df_1['x'] = df_1['x'].replace('-', '')
df_1['x'].head()
```

I get the same data

and if I try this

```
df_1['x'] = str(df_1['x]).replace('-', '')
```

my data gets all muddied.

can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like a minus, what if you use `df_1['x'].abs()` instead?

Comment: your data type isn't `str`. The second command has missing `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and i'm trying to replace the '-' sign with ''

These are (likely) not strings but numbers, the `-` means it is a negative number. Given that these are negative numbers, it perhaps is not a good idea to remove the minus, since `-5` of course is something different than `5`.

In case you want to map negative numbers on their positive counterpart, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.abs(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) for that, to calculate the *absolute value*:

```
df_1['x'] = df_1['x'].abs()
```